# SP 2013 workflow initiation form people picker

Tags: workflow, people-picker, visual-studio-2012, initiation-form

Using a WorkflowInitiationForm in an VisualStudio workflow for SharePoint 2013 I wonder how to get the Information from people picker.
Adding to the project the form delivers code examples for string, integer and datetime, but not for the used people picker.

Is it something like

```
params['users'] = document.getElementById("ctl00_PlaceHolderMain_???PeoplePicker???").value;
```

to pass the value(s) to the startWorkflow() parameters?

useful links:

- [blog.loitzl.com](http://blog.loitzl.com/wp-content/uploads/2013/02/7-Add-Initiation-Form-Code-changed.png)

Answer (score 1):

You can find the People picker control id using browser developer tools.

Use below code to get the user login

```
var pickerElement = document.getElementById("pickerid");
params['user'] = pickerElement.getAttribute("key");
```

Comment: hmh, retrieves null in my case !?

Comment: @Celophysis have you modified the `pickerid` to match your picker control id?

Comment: yes, I've modified it - should it work without a executeQueryAsync?

Comment: No you need executeQuery.. Can you post the complete code?

Comment: I turned over to use http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/jj713593%28v=office.15%29.aspx - this works for me